# Writing $2$-cycles as a product of adjacent 2-cycles.

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, permutations, symmetric-groups, permutation-cycles

**Problem**: Consider the arbitrary 2-cycle $(a\ b)$ from $S_n$. Find a way to write this permutation as a product of adjacent 2-cycles.

What I do know:

A transposition is a single cycle of length 2. An adjacent transposition is of the form $(i\ i+1)$. For example, $(3\ 7)$ is a non-adjacent transposition, but $(3,4)$ is an adjacent transposition. It turns out that the set of transpositions for $S_n$ is a generating set for $S_n$.

So, to write the arbitrary 2-cycle $(a\ b)$ from $S_n$ as a product of 2 adjacent cycles, would it look something like this:

I can start at some arbitrary values, say, $(1\ 2)$. Then,

$(1\ 2)(a\ a+1)(a+1\ a+2)\cdots(b-2\ b-1)(b-1\ b)$ and eventually, I will get to $(a\ b)$?

I guess my question is, would this be a valid answer or would I need to generalize it more? And, is it ok to start at some arbitrary values such as the one I chose? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you familiar with the fact that for any permutation $\sigma\in S_n$ you have
$$\sigma(a\ b)\sigma^{-1}=(\sigma(a),\sigma(b))?$$

Comment: @Servaes I am not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general the product of adjacent transpositions
$$(1\ 2)(a\ a+1)(a+1\ a+2)\cdots(b-2\ b-1)(b-1\ b),$$
does *not* eventually reach $(a\ b)$. For example, if $(a\ b)=(3\ 4)$ then your product is
$$(1\ 2)(3\ 4)\neq(3\ 4).$$
A less degenerate example would be $(a\ b)=(4\ 8)$. Then your product is
$$(1\ 2)(4\ 5)(5\ 6)(6\ 7)(7\ 8)=(1\ 2)(4\ 5\ 6\ 7\ 8)\neq(4\ 8).$$

In stead, use the fact that
$$(c\ c+1)(a\ c)(c\ c+1)=(a\ c+1).$$
In this way, starting from $c=a+1$ we get
$$(a+1\ a+2)(a\ a+1)(a+1\ a+2)=(a\ a+2),$$
then again with $c=a+2$ to get
$$(a+2\ a+3)(a+1\ a+2)(a\ a+1)(a+1\ a+2)(a+2\ a+3)=(a\ a+3),$$
and you can continue this way all the way to $c=b-1$ to get $(a\ b)$.

Comment: So, if we have $$(a\ a+1)(a\ b)(a\ a+1)=(a+1\ b)$$ I guess I am not seeing the big picture and generalization on how this is writing $(a\ b)$ as adjacent 2-cycles. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Perhaps it would have been better to suggest the 'reverse' equality, let me update my answer to be more clear.

Comment: Thanks for the help.